# Income Tax Refund

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax-refund

I used to work in Maryland, United States from 1999 to 2002.

During this I paid all taxes:

- Federal Income Tax
- Social Security Tax
- Medicare Tax
- MD State Income Tax

I returned back to India during 2002 and have been working here ever since. Is there a way I can get some of the taxes I paid in the US refunded

Comment: Why do you think you are due a refund?

Comment: While you may feel in your situation that paying social security and medicare was a waste because you will never use those programs; the Federal and State taxes were used to pay for services you did use.

Comment: @EkoostikMartin: Some countries (such as Canada) do refund some taxes when visitors leave the country again. However, those are limited to very specific sales taxes, and I don't think the US has anything which even approaches that limited refund.

Answer (score 4):

The income taxes are not refundable just because you later leave the country. The taxes are based upon the income you've earned while in the US, what you did before or after is irrelevant. They cover the various government expenditures during that period (i.e.: government services you were receiving, like roads, bridges, police, security, etc etc).

Social Security taxes provide you some benefit, if you pay them long enough. While in your case you haven't gotten enough credits, many foreigners who end up staying in the US can claim the SS taxes paid while on visa towards their SS benefit credits. Unless there's a totalization agreement between your home country and the US, if you didn't earn enough credits for benefits - these taxes are lost as well. If you ever get back to the US - you can continue accumulating credits from the point you left.